# Setting global configuration for angular datatables

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm a little new to angular and was wondering how I can set the global configuration for datatables. Currently it seems I can only set it within each component that need to use it, but this is clearly bad practice. Is there any way to set the configuration globally and have it be available to all component templates?

I want to be able to set the below in a single location and have any component template access it through `[dt-options]="dtOptions"`

```
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {
    language: {
        paginate: {
            first: "",
            previous: "<<",
            next: ">>",
            last: ""
        }
    },
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
}
```

Hope this makes sense

**Angular version:** 12.2.3

**Datatables version:** 12.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `environment.ts` files. This files then can be imported inside your component.

```
// inside environment.ts    
export const dtOptions = {
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: "",
                previous: "<<",
                next: ">>",
                last: ""
            }
        },
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    }
```

Use your configuration inside your components like here:

```
import { dtOptions} from '../path/to/environment.ts';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit() {
     console.log(dtOptions.language);
   }
}
```

---

It is also possible to create different environment configurations for each stage `configuration` defined in `angular.json`.

[Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#using-environment-specific-variables-in-your-app)

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks. However, when I try to add this to the environment.ts file the `DataTables.Settings` throws the error "Cannot use namespace 'DataTables' as a value." and the `export` throws the error "Declaration or statement expected."

Comment: You have to define either a type or an interface instead using DataTables.Settings. Could you please show whats behind 'DataTables.Settings'

Comment: It works if I add it like this. This what you meant? `export const environment = {
    production: false,
    dtOptions: {
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: "",
                previous: "<<",
                next: ">>",
                last: ""
            }
        },
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    }
};` And then I am able to assign it in my component like this: `dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = environment.dtOptions;`

Comment: Yes somehow i forgot to add the const keyword. I´ll update the anwser